# Edges in compound shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

I am trying to create geometric shapes by joining closed paths together, as shown in this example

[image]

However, when adding stroke to the paths, each object create its own corners:

[image]

I tried creating a compound path with the 3 objects selected but I had no luck. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Use round corners or make the outermost triangle the main object

Comment: What's a main object joojaa? I think this could be what I'm looking for

Comment: Setting the path to inside the stroke line could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not, there is no such thing as a three way curve end. See there ate two simple generalizations of curves:

1. Each and every segment is separate, this can not span an area
2. Or a multi segment curve where each curve end follows a second end. This allows you to make closed areas.

Admittedly you could expand this to a network mesh. But the complexity from a users perspective would blow up. Meshes are just harder to handle and you would have even more cryptic problems than you have now (how would you round a 3 way join?) And quite frankly theres more things we could use our time on.

So how do you solve this? Essentially 2 ways, which incidentally are the related to the ways to model thing above:

1. Use a corner type that is the same in all configurations. In other words use round corners. No problems.
2. Don't think of the internal lines as closed shapes, but separate lines.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After you merge the shape you simply need to select the `rounded corners` option in the Stroke menu.

[image]